# Error in using tidyverse function pivot_wider

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyr

[enter image description here][1]Dear all,
I have a very large file (14,566,680 records) with 2 variables (ID and A).
The first variable (ID) is the individual (n=258) and each individual has 56,460 records (A)

I would like to write out a "transpose" file (i.e. 258 lines & 54460 columns).

When I execute the following code:

```
system.time(snp1 %>% 
  #filter(`Sample ID`=='8362974') %>% 
  select(`Sample ID`,A) %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
  #head(n=nsnp) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from=id,
              values_from = A)->T)
```

I got the following error:

```
Error in rep_len(NA_integer_, n) : invalid 'length.out' value
In addition: Warning message:
In nrow * ncol : NAs produced by integer overflow
Timing stopped at: 28.73 0.62 29.36
```

If I use only 1 ID it works correctly

Best
Stefano

Comment: Looks like the output is too long. Weird

Comment: You inserted a tag for an image but forgot the url for it

Comment: Took another look, Your function call is wrong, You will have a column in the output for each id meaning you get a huge matrix, makes sense it doesn't work

Comment: Can you make this [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)? Without any data we can't run your code, and it's unclear what's going wrong since we can't see either what you're starting with or what you're trying to get

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does it work if you group the records by individual before calculating the row_number  (record ID)?

```
# made up sample
df <- tibble(`Sample ID` = rep(1:258, each = 56460)) %>%
  mutate(A = rnorm(nrow(.)))

df %>%
  group_by(`Sample ID`) %>%
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from=id,
              values_from = A)

# A tibble: 258 x 56,461
# Groups:   Sample ID [258]
   `Sample ID`    `1`    `2`     `3`     `4`      `5`     `6`    `7`
         <int>  <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>
 1           1  1.49   0.546  0.0517 -0.480  -0.500    0.266  -1.52 
 2           2 -0.391 -0.855 -1.28   -0.0277 -0.999    0.617  -0.415
 3           3  0.200  0.484  1.08   -0.568   1.16     1.75   -0.143
 4           4  0.212  0.371  0.674   0.0481 -1.09    -1.07    0.160
 5           5  0.409  1.54   0.931  -0.280   1.27     0.0447  0.426
 6           6 -0.936  0.903 -0.0408  0.590  -1.52    -1.14   -0.600
 7           7 -1.97   0.336 -0.233   0.488   0.995   -0.933  -1.90 
 8           8 -0.396  2.12   1.10    0.304   0.290    0.595  -1.32 
 9           9 -1.31  -0.124 -0.804  -0.447   1.12    -0.721   0.378
10          10  0.977  0.818  1.51   -0.258  -0.00794  0.0386  2.03 
# ... with 248 more rows, and 56,453 more variables: ...
```